# Comparing and understanding my linear regression result with a previous attempt

Tags: r, regression, experiment-design

**Update: I wanted to clarify that this is a simulation. Sorry if I confused everyone. I have also used meaningful names for my variables.**

I am not a statistician so please correct me if I make a blunder in explaining what I want. In regard to my [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/what-is-a-good-way-of-estimating-the-dependence-of-an-output-variable-on-the-inpu), I have reproduced parts of my question here for reference.

> I am evaluating a scenario's output
>   dependence on three
>   variables: Area, Speed and NumOfVehicles. For this, I am
>   conducting the following experiments:
>
> - Fix Area+Speed, Vary NumOfVehicles - Total four sets of (Area+Speed) each having 4 variations of NumOfVehicles
> - Fix Speed+NumOfVehicles, Vary Area - Total four sets of (Speed+NumOfVehicles) each having 3 variations of Area
> - Fix NumOfVehicles+Area, Vary Speed - Total four sets of (NumOfVehicles+Area) each having 6 variations of Speed
>
> The output of any simulation is the
>   value of a variable over time. The output
>   variable I am observing is the time at which 80% of the cars crashe.
>
> I am trying to determine which
>   parameter(s) dominate the outcome of
>   the experiment. By dominate, I mean
>   that sometimes, the outcomes just does
>   not change when one of the parameters
>   change but when some other parameter
>   is changed even by a small amount, a
>   large change in the output is
>   observed. I need to capture this
>   effect and output some analysis from
>   which I can understand the dependence
>   of the output on the input parameters.
>   A friend suggested Sensitivity
>   Analysis but am not sure if there are
>   simpler ways of doing it. Can someone
>   please help me with a good (possibly
>   easy because I don't have a Stats
>   background) technique? It would be
>   great if all this can be done in R.

My previous result was not very satisfactory looking at the regression results. So what I did was that I went ahead and repeated all my experiments 20 times each with different variations of each variable (so for instance, instead of 4 variations of Area, I now have 8 and so on). Following is the summary I obtained out of R after using linear regression:

```
Call:
lm(formula = T ~ Area + Speed + NumOfVehicles)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.13315 -0.06332 -0.01346  0.04484  0.29676 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)      0.04285    0.02953   1.451    0.148    
Area             0.70285    0.02390  29.406  < 2e-16 ***
Speed           -0.15560    0.02080  -7.479 2.12e-12 ***
NumOfVehicles   -0.27447    0.02927  -9.376  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.08659 on 206 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.8304, Adjusted R-squared: 0.8279 
F-statistic: 336.2 on 3 and 206 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

as opposed to my previous result:

```
lm(formula = T ~ Area + Speed + NumOfVehicles)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.35928 -0.06842 -0.00698  0.05591  0.42844 

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   -0.01606    0.16437  -0.098 0.923391    
Area           0.80199    0.15792   5.078 0.000112 ***
Speed         -0.27440    0.13160  -2.085 0.053441 .  
NumOfVehicles -0.31898    0.14889  -2.142 0.047892 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.1665 on 16 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared: 0.6563, Adjusted R-squared: 0.5919 
F-statistic: 10.18 on 3 and 16 DF,  p-value: 0.0005416
```

From my understanding, my current results have a lower standard error so that is good. In addition the Pr value also seems quite low which tells me that this result is better than my previous result. So can I go ahead and say that A has the maximum effect on the output and then come S and V in that order? Can I make any other deductions from this result?

Also, I was suggested that I look into adding additional variates like $A^2$ etc. but if $A$ is the area, what does saying "time" depends on $A^2$ actually mean?

Comment: I recommend you change the title. The answer to the question 'is this result good or bad' is subjective, and would depend on what the predictor variables are - as well as the values of the respondent. Car mechanics / salesmen / manufacturers might prefer more crashes, a car driver might prefer less. The size of the estimate of a standard error is just that - there is no reason to think that smaller is better without context. Perhaps you want to know if your results support your hypothesis or not, or if your results are valid, in which case you would be able to find useful answers here.

Comment: @David: +1 Thank you for the suggestion. I changed it to a comparison question. Hope this is ok. I should have qualified my question with a simulation tag. I am evaluating my scenarios from a driver's perspective so less crashes is better. My original hypothesis was that the output (time at which 80% of the cars crash) does not depend on the three parameters. But from my results, I am tempted to say that I can reject my hypothesis but how strongly I can reject is still something I am looking into but thank you for the insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, to begin with, I think it was ok to rephrase the question in your previous post, now I just remember I have read it, but all the discussion is lost. I beg pardons if the ideas here are repeated (was lazy to search for the original post).

There are some doubts regarding your experimental scheme and conclusions:

1. Is the data you are working with: 3 explanatory variables A, V and S (not A, B, C as you wrote and it is nor correct to call them *parameters*, parameters are the coefficients you estimate by linear regression) and the dependent T, true empirical data you observe in real life or you just simulate the data based on some likely values that you *believe* are true? However even in *believable* profile of the attributes (T, A, V, S) what is the joint distribution then? The conclusion that the data is not from real observations: goes from here
   *So what I did was that I went ahead and repeated all my experiments 20 times each with different variations of each parameters (so for instance, instead of 4 variations of A, I now have 8 and so on).*
   Thus there is (I guess) little to do with [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28statistics%29) or any other re-sampling techniques or Monte Carlo simulations. Therefore by manually setting the experimental design you do the conclusions that have little empirical background. I wish to be wrong in this place though.
2. Impacts of the variables are not measured by the value of parameters NOR by the smaller standard errors, p values! If you wish to compare the impacts in terms of marginal effects you need to implement the [standardized regression](http://www.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats1/x92.pdf) coefficients also known as beta coefficients. You can calculate them manually (coef()*sd()/sd()) or redo the regressions scaling all 4 variables first with `scale()` function. You may compare then the marginal effects that are represented by beta parameters. Standardized data is dimensionless so you may compare the impacts of different explanatory variables.
3. However if the variables are slowly varying and strictly positive you may be interested not in marginal impacts, but in percent changes that are given by [elasticities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_a_function) of different variables. Take the original model and estimated parameters coef() and multiply it by mean()/mean(), in additive model you get mean elasticity then. Note that you can't do the same in standardized (zero-mean) model, and since the fractions are in general different so will be betas and elasticities. The interpretation of elasticity is straightforward if the explanatory variable changes by 1 per cent what is the per cent change of dependent variable.

All other suggestion like take transformations, add some other variables ($A^2$ for example) comes from the further statistical inspection of the residuals for regression's traditional weak spots: is linear model a good approximation (RESET), no multicollinearity (VIF, CI), no heteroscedasticity (White or any other), no autocorrelation (DW, Ljung-Box, etc.)  and so on.

P.S. the current result is neither good nor bad, it is just looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @Dimitrij Celov: +1 for your time. I am sorry about my question. I fixed all the mistakes (parameters->variables) and giving more meaningful names to the variables. And sorry about not linking to my previous question (somehow I thought I did). I also clarified that this question is based on simulation and not on real-life empirical values. The values I am using are just values that are believed to be ok as there has been no real experiment. I am designing a protocol but before doing that, I wanted to understand the dynamics of my environment. I am still reading your post to digest everything.

Comment: @Legend, the first regression you made was based on 20 points, now they are not doubled but 10 times bigger, 210 points you use in the second regression (at least F-test's degrees of freedom state that). What I am confused about is the joint probability that the certain *believed to be ok* combination of variables should be introduced in your *artificial* sample. To make "meaningful" comparisons do the 2 step in the post (compute beta coefficients), "" implies that conclusions will be subjective and not practical (but you may still try to do formal estimation).

Answer (score 1):

This result looks great. One thing that I would recommend doing is looking at the residuals for each of the two models to see if there are any trends in the first model that are not present in the second. If the model has residuals with an approximately normal distribution then you won't need to add more terms like A^2. The command for this is:

```
my_model <- (formula = T ~ A + S + V)
resid(my_model
```

Comment: @user3727: +1 I am not sure I am doing this right but when I do `resid(my_model)` on my second one I am getting a NULL. At this point, I am not sure I should be considering the previous attempt because the experiment design was pretty careless on my part.